# Revolve $y=e^{-x}$ about $x=1$?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, volume

I wanted to ask what I think is a fairly simple question for most of you on here!

Revolve the curve $$y=e^{-x}$$ bounded by $y=0$, $x=0$, $x=-1$ about the $x=1$ axis.
I am supposed to use the method of shells.
Here is my attempt at a solution:
$$2\pi\int_{-1}^0 (1+x)(e^{-x})dx$$
Which comes out to $2\pi(e-2)$. However the correct answer is $2\pi(e)$. 
Any help would be great as my final is coming up.

Comment: What formula for shells did you use?

Comment: What is the radius of each shell?

Comment: The $(1+x)$ factor does not look right. Could you double-check that?

Answer (score 1):

Radius of cylinder is 1-x. The fact that x is negative is not relevant.